# Should I close this question and ask a different one somewhere else?

Tags: discussion, support, specific-question

I asked this question (let's call it A):

[tmux 2.6: why does copying mouse-selected text to macOS clipboard work in iTerm but not in Warp and VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74646440/tmux-2-6-why-does-copying-mouse-selected-text-to-macos-clipboard-work-in-iterm)

A user made this interesting comment:

> `tmux` doesn't know anything about terminal emulators; it only knows
> about terminal features. Moving data from `tmux` to a terminal emulator
> requires the terminal emulator to implement the features that `tmux`
> uses. So the question is, does VS Code or Warp support the required
> features?

The user notes that the real question is B="do VS Code or Warp support the features required from `tmux` to allow copying to OS X clipboard?", and of course I have no idea. So what do I do now?

1. Should I ask question B? Here? On [Super User](https://superuser.com/tour)? On [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/tour)? [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour)? I'm using the terminal emulator (VS Code or Warp) to connect to a remote Ubuntu server, from an OS X laptop, so I'm not sure which place would be more appropriate (I would think Ask Ubuntu).
2. Should I close question A? To me, it doesn't seem identical to question B, so I'd rather leave it open to see if it attracts any answers, but if you think I'd better close, just let me know.

Comment: It's [expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/) to do that kind of analysis before asking, if possible; but I feel like A would be off-topic even if it weren't a proxy for B.

Comment: (Warp is a terminal emulator for Mac only ([at the moment](https://github.com/warpdotdev/warp/issues/120)). Wasn't it recently mentioned on the podcast? It isn't commercial in the start phase, [but that may or may not change](https://github.com/warpdotdev/Warp/discussions/400) (my emphasis): *"Our business model is that we are free for everyone* ***for now*** *and will eventually experiment with different premium features for enterprise."*)

Comment: You may want to consider [apple.se] rather than [ubuntu.se] if you're using macOS... But this question might be better asked on [meta.se].

Comment: @KarlKnechtel you're right, but I did the analysis and I thought it would be ok here. Then the user's comment made me realize that pheraps I made a mistake, so I asked here.

Comment: @PeterMortensen how would Warp business model influence where I should ask the question? This is a genuine question, not at all trying to be hostile.

Comment: @HereticMonkey ouch! I started with a single question, then a Meta question...I'm a bit hesitant to ask a _third_ question somewhere else. What if we decide first of all if 1) A is on-topic here, 2) B would be on-topic here? If they are on-topic, then I don't have to ask on Meta SE. If they're not, then I'll ask there. Deal?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel as a proof of my good will, I can link to numerous "tmux and macOS clipboard" questions here on SO, that made me think initially that the question would be on-topic here. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45255359/tmux-and-macos-clipboard/47320968 and in case you were wondering: I asked a new question because the answer to that question doesn't work in my case (VS Code or Warp).

Comment: @DeltaIV Just because there are questions about tmux on SO does not mean they are on-topic. The linked question sis definitely off-topic here as the question has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: Maybe you'd feel more comfortable asking that over on [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/). There are lots of users with extensive knowledge of such things over there.

Comment: @DeltaV: The question you linked as an example has now been closed for being off-topic. For future reference: The existence of a question on SO does not automatically mean that the question is on-topic. Things occasionally get missed, and there are also questions here that at one time were acceptable to ask but are not any longer due to the creation of new sites. For instance, there are general computer and software questions here that were on-topic when they were asked, but wouldn't be now because [su] was created for them.

Comment: Also, IMO neither A or B is appropriate for SO, as they are not programming related.. They both would seem to be more suitable for [su] as a general software question.

Comment: @KenWhite I understand that things must be different now, but please let's not frame it as if I saw _one_ question and automatically assumed the subject would be on-topic here. A simple search "tmux mouse copy" finds _many such questions_, such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32374907/tmux-mouse-copy-mode-jumps-to-bottom https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17445100/getting-back-old-copy-paste-behaviour-in-tmux-with-mouse https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12287432/how-to-copy-to-system-clipboard-from-tmux-output-after-mouse-selection...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62544783/how-to-disable-mouse-copy-while-keeping-mouse-scroll-in-tmux https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36815879/tmux-copy-mouse-selected-text-to-clipboard-automatically-on-mouse-release and more (some no more than 2 years old). Anyway, I get your point. I closed the question and opened an identical one on Super User.

Comment: @DeltaV: Once again, **the existence  of a question on SO does NOT automatically mean that the question is on-topic**. Linking of other existing posts is meaningless.

Comment: Hostile? Please always assume good intent. I even put it the ***parentheses*** as an indication. It was just to provide some ***context***: They are very unclear about whether it is commercial or not. And whether it for Mac only or not. And they also don't advertise that ***you have to have an account by them to use it***. And that GitHub is not for the source code (at the moment), even though they suggest it is all open source (the source code for the client will be open sourced, but not the server side) by saying what programming language they use (Rust). They really ought to say it upfront.